# paypal verify payment

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am testing PayPal payments through Sandbox. So what do I do:

1. Make a payment from my Android device, using SDK AppID: "APP-80W284485P519543T".
2. Receive `RESULT_OK` in `applicationResult` and receive response on server side through IPN service.
3. Now I am taking all responce from IPN and send it to paypal verification sandbox server to verify payment. It cat return (VERIFIED or INVALID).

But the problem is that it is  return INVALID. So whats can be the problem? What I am doing wrong? Thanks.

This is what I send to verify:

> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate&payment_request_date=Mon+Mar+26+02%3A37%3A10+PDT+2012&fees_payer=EACHRECEIVER&transaction[0].is_primary_receiver=false&memo=Buy+1500+coins&transaction_type=Adaptive+Payment+PAY&verify_sign=AWimjEpfvS2eR6IgBwHtiwM0rMDUA.b2twU2ADjkAY-kg5szeluxcqKb&log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction=false&pay_key=AP-2YR77828AV574621G&transaction[0].amount=USD+1.99&reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error=true&ipn_notification_url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev-vs.upiter.com%2Fvspayment%2Fproviders%2Fvs%2Ffb%2Fpaypalcallback&action_type=CREATE&notify_version=UNVERSIONED&transaction[0].status_for_sender_txn=Pending&test_ipn=1&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paypal.com&transaction[0].pending_reason=UNILATERAL&status=COMPLETED&charset=windows-1252&transaction[0].paymentType=GOODS&request_body=&request_url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev-vs-mobile.stagika.com%2Fvspayment%2Fproviders%2Fvs%2Ffb%2Fpaypalcallback&return_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paypal.com&transaction[0].receiver=a.merchant1.kv%40gmail.com&request_method=POST&transaction[0].id_for_sender_txn=0X355330VH030952T&sender.useCredentials=true

Comment: For, payment in android. They've provide a best example [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk#7) Just refer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad callback (IPN) from Paypal. It include false parameters.
I think there is some problem with [setIpnUrl(String IPNURL)](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Android.pdf) for the Android.

Try to use static IPN URL set in the [Profile in the seller Accaunt](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNSetup). It have started to work for me!